# How to convert my stats calculated array to 2 decimals?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The following line of code prints the standard deviation and mean on my graph using matplotlib in python. My question is. How do I convert the values to 2 decimals?

```
ax.text(60, 0.01, r'$\mu={},\ \sigma={}$'.format(np.mean(stat_input),np.std(stat_input)))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "2 decimals"? What are you currently getting, and what do you want to get?

Comment: I get mu = 54.38493289325 and Sigma = 48.48389489348

I would like 54.38 and 48.48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(123.456789)
'123.46'
```

For details see: [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

So, in your case the line becomes:

```
ax.text(60, 0.01, r'$\mu={:.2f},\ \sigma={:.2f}$'.format(
    np.mean(stat_input), np.std(stat_input)
))
```

Comment: I get this. I don't know how to incorporate it into the line of code that I wrote. I am not a python pro, I am a beginner.

Comment: @ShibbyBoss updated. You can use this syntax inside the `{}`

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now.  I tried something similar but was missing a character.
Thank you